# How to get the number of columns occupied by a character in terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal

[How to justify and center text in bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/823883/how-to-justify-and-center-text-in-bash) shows how to center text in bash. It only works if each character occupies one column, such as English letters. There are many characters that occupy at least two columns each, such as "你好".

How to get the number of columns occupied by a specified character in terminal?

Comment: Do you have an example of a character that occupies multiple columns?

Comment: The `get_width` function in https://github.com/urwid/urwid/blob/master/urwid/old_str_util.py can solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

One simple option is GNU `wc`. From the man page:

> `-L`, `--max-line-length`
>   print the maximum display width

So for the example in your comments:

```
$ wc -L <<< '你好'
4
```

This can be made into a little function:

```
getwidth () {
    for str; do
        echo "$str: $(wc -L <<< "$str")"
    done
}
```

This can be used as follows:

```
$ getwidth 你 好 a
你: 2
好: 2
a: 1
```

[This Unix & Linux Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245013/get-the-display-width-of-a-string-of-characters) has a few good pointers.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/urwid/urwid/blob/master/urwid/old_str_util.py gives an alternative answer in which `get width` can get the width of a character by its unicode ordinal.

```
widths = [
    (126, 1),
    (159, 0),
    (687, 1),
    (710, 0),
    (711, 1),
    (727, 0),
    (733, 1),
    (879, 0),
    (1154, 1),
    (1161, 0),
    (4347, 1),
    (4447, 2),
    (7467, 1),
    (7521, 0),
    (8369, 1),
    (8426, 0),
    (9000, 1),
    (9002, 2),
    (11021, 1),
    (12350, 2),
    (12351, 1),
    (12438, 2),
    (12442, 0),
    (19893, 2),
    (19967, 1),
    (55203, 2),
    (63743, 1),
    (64106, 2),
    (65039, 1),
    (65059, 0),
    (65131, 2),
    (65279, 1),
    (65376, 2),
    (65500, 1),
    (65510, 2),
    (120831, 1),
    (262141, 2),
    (1114109, 1),
]

# ACCESSOR FUNCTIONS

def get_width( o ):
    """Return the screen column width for unicode ordinal o."""
    global widths
    if o == 0xe or o == 0xf:
        return 0
    for num, wid in widths:
        if o <= num:
            return wid
    return 1
```

https://github.com/someus/terminal-text-width gives the corresponding implementation by node.